# Django-Taggit validate newly added tags before save

Tags: django, django-taggit, wagtail

This is how my models look like. I was not able to do the validation by overriding the save method of either of the models.

```
class NotificationListTag(TaggedItemBase):
    content_object = models.ForeignKey('Mailer')


class Mailer(models.Model):

    from_email = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    to_emails = TaggableManager(
        through=NotificationListTag,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name='To Emails',
        help_text='Space separated email ID'
    )
```

How do I validate each of the newly added tags before it gets saved. Did I miss something out.

Comment: I think you've made some mistakes while "anonymising" this code: 1) the ParentalKey refers to UnchainedMailer, not Mailer; 2) if you're using ParentalKey, you also need to use ClusterableModel and ClusterTaggableManager on Mailer; otherwise, the ParentalKey should just be a ForeignKey. (I'd suggest trying to get this to work first with just a plain ForeignKey - that way, there are fewer moving parts).

Comment: @gasman By ForeignKey do you mean to implement like this http://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/custom_tagging.html#custom-tag by using a custom tag ?

Comment: @gasman So i tried switching to ForeignKey, but I'm still not able to intercept the proper save method. The tag that I want to be checked always get created. 

Is there a way in wagtail I can intercept it in the form level ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a custom API for the tagging autocomplete suggestions, that only suggests valid names.

You can override the the `tagit.js` call wagtail makes by default, to pass your custom autocomplete URL to it. In this way, you don't have to do validation after the user has entered a value.